# JSP Page with Oracle Query with to_date function error

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to execute below query in a JSP page on Oracle DB

```
"SELECT * FROM  message_detail_tmp 
  WHERE UPDATED_DATE between to_date('20190227 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') 
                         and to_date('20190228 23:59:59', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')"
```

Getting below error when the web-app started in tomcat

```
An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /getData.jsp
Connection cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please help resolve the issue.

It is working fine if I change the query to :

```
"SELECT * FROM  message_detail_tmp WHERE UPDATED_DATE > sysdate -1"
```

Comment: I already added the required imports. It is working if I remove the to_date function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your query to the style below against date formatting problems :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM message_detail_tmp 
 WHERE updated_date >= date'2019-02-27'
   and updated_date <  date'2019-03-01'
```

If you need hours, minutes and seconds you can try the following cases :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM message_detail_tmp 
 WHERE updated_date >= timestamp'2019-02-27 15:00:00'
   and updated_date <  timestamp'2019-02-28 16:00:00'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM message_detail_tmp 
 WHERE updated_date between timestamp'2019-02-27 15:00:00'
                        and timestamp'2019-02-28 16:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, Barbaros, but I would like to be able to filter for records during particular hours or minutes of a day as well.

Comment: @AKPuvvada you're welcome Puvvada. I edited the question due to your last wish.